# SQL Server: SELECT XML with Namespaces gives NULL Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I want to load a XML File into SQL Server 2012 as a variable, one of the columns should contain the XML itself and the other columns should contain values from the XML elements.
My Issue is that I don't get an ERROR but also no record in my table, it just returned blank result

```sql
USE [testjrazt]
GO
DECLARE @doc XML
SELECT @doc = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SyncSalesOrder xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.12.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncSalesOrder.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.12.x">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <Sender>
            <LogicalID>lid://infor.ln.dach_nausveln1_200_2</LogicalID>
            <ComponentID>erp</ComponentID>
            <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
        </Sender>
        <CreationDateTime>2019-12-02T15:47:42Z</CreationDateTime>
        <BODID>infor-nid:infor:200::AA0000008:?SalesOrder&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Sync>
            <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
            <AccountingEntityID>200</AccountingEntityID>
            <LocationID>
        </LocationID>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <SalesOrder>
        --CUT FOR BETTER READABILITY 
    </SalesOrder>
</DataArea>
</SyncSalesOrder>
'

--Inserting into COR_Outbox_Entry Tabelle -> I/O BOX 
/*
INSERT INTO [dbo].[COR_OUTBOX_ENTRY]
           ([C_XML]
           ,[C_TENANT_ID]
           ,[C_MESSAGE_PRIORITY] 
           ,[C_CREATED_DATE_TIME]
           ,[C_WAS_PROCESSED]
           ,[C_LOGICAL_ID])
*/
--Only SELECT to check if data get loaded from XML - BLANK RESULT 
SELECT 
    i_xml = CAST (@doc AS varbinary(max)),
    i_tenant_id = xdoc.value('(DataArea/Sync/TenantID)[1]','nvarchar(250)'), -- xpath /SyncSalesOrder/DataArea/Sync/TenantID
    --i_message_priority =xdoc.value('()[1]','int'),
    i_created_date_time = xdoc.value('(ApplicationArea/CreationDateTime)[1]','datetime'),
    --i_was_processed = xdoc.value('()[1]','int'),
    i_lid = xdoc.value('(ApplicationArea/Sender/LogicalID)[1]','nvarchar(250)')
FROM @doc.nodes('SyncSalesOrder') AS InputTable(xdoc)
```

Comment: The `INSERT INTO` is commented out in your SQL, so no, it won't `INSERT` anything.

Comment: @jrazt, It is better to use XML data type for the [C_XML] column.

Comment: @Larnu i know, i commented the `INSERT INTO` out because i wanted to see first through the SELECT which data would be inserted.  Like a safe checking before filling the table

Comment: you can add a namespace declaration to the `nodes()` parameter, or use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky i see what u mean by that but unfortunately i had to create this and a few more tables out of a script and for later use it must be a varbinary, so i cant go the easy way and i have to use a cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it. Your XML has a default namespace. It should be taken into account via `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause.

```sql
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @doc XML = 
N'<SyncSalesOrder xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/2.12.x/InforOAGIS/BODs/SyncSalesOrder.xsd"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" releaseID="9.2"
                versionID="2.12.x">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <Sender>
            <LogicalID>lid://infor.ln.dach_nausveln1_200_2</LogicalID>
            <ComponentID>erp</ComponentID>
            <ConfirmationCode>OnError</ConfirmationCode>
        </Sender>
        <CreationDateTime>2019-12-02T15:47:42Z</CreationDateTime>
        <BODID>infor-nid:infor:200::AA0000008:?SalesOrder&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Sync>
            <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
            <AccountingEntityID>200</AccountingEntityID>
            <LocationID>
            </LocationID>
            <ActionCriteria>
                <ActionExpression actionCode="Add"/>
            </ActionCriteria>
        </Sync>
        <SalesOrder>--CUT FOR BETTER READABILITY</SalesOrder>
    </DataArea>
</SyncSalesOrder>';

DECLARE @COR_OUTBOX_ENTRY TABLE ([C_XML] XML
           ,[C_TENANT_ID] NVARCHAR(250)
           --,[C_MESSAGE_PRIORITY] 
           ,[C_CREATED_DATE_TIME] DATETIME
           --,[C_WAS_PROCESSED]
           ,[C_LOGICAL_ID] NVARCHAR(250));
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2')
INSERT INTO @COR_OUTBOX_ENTRY
           ([C_XML]
           ,[C_TENANT_ID]
           --,[C_MESSAGE_PRIORITY] 
           ,[C_CREATED_DATE_TIME]
           --,[C_WAS_PROCESSED]
           ,[C_LOGICAL_ID])
SELECT  @doc AS i_xml
    , i_tenant_id = c.value('(DataArea/Sync/TenantID/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)')
--i_message_priority =xdoc.value('()[1]','int'),
    , i_created_date_time = c.value('(ApplicationArea/CreationDateTime/text())[1]','datetime')
--i_was_processed = xdoc.value('()[1]','int'),
    , i_lid = c.value('(ApplicationArea/Sender/LogicalID/text())[1]','nvarchar(250)')
FROM @doc.nodes('/SyncSalesOrder') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @COR_OUTBOX_ENTRY;
```