# Select XML node that match name

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

My XML structure looks like this

[image]

From XML I need to select node **HHQuoteData** from **KeyValuePair/Value** collection

My code below doesn't return any data. What is wrong with my code?

```
SELECT
    k.kv.query('KeyValuePair/Value/HHQuoteData')
FROM DeclinedQuote.RequestLogXMLsToProcess aph
CROSS APPLY [PayloadXML].nodes('/server/requests/Session.setDocumentRq/session/data/policy/AdditionalData') A (ad)
CROSS APPLY a.ad.nodes('KeyValuePair') k (kv)
WHERE k.kv.exist('(/Value[contains(.,"HHQuoteData")])') = 1
```

[Sample xml](http://pastie.org/p/4fH7JkJjDehezmv8VHg3IR)

Comment: Your `AdditionalData` belongs to namespace `http://www.fc.com/quote/request/`. You are asking for `AdditionalData` that belongs to  an empty namespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server: SELECT XML with Namespaces gives NULL Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067251/sql-server-select-xml-with-namespaces-gives-null-result)

Comment: Tried the WITH XMLNAMESPACES, AdditionalData belongs to http://www.fc.com/quote/request/   but the AdditionalData/KeyValuePair/Value belong to  http://www.fc.com/quote.  How can I handle this namespace

Comment: @Iptr . Thanks. your code works. Learned something new today..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another answer from @lptr in a comment...

```
with xmlnamespaces
(
'http://www.fc.com/quote/request/' as r, 
'http://www.fc.com/quote/' as q, 
'http://www.fc.com/householdaggregator/request' as hr
)
select a.d.query('.')
from @x.nodes('server/requests/Session.setDocumentRq/session/data/policy/r:AdditionalData/r:KeyValuePair/q:Value/hr:HHQuoteData') as a(d);

with xmlnamespaces('http://www.fc.com/quote/request/' as r, 'http://www.fc.com/quote/' as q)
select a.d.query('.')
from @x.nodes('server/requests/Session.setDocumentRq/session/data/policy/r:AdditionalData/r:KeyValuePair/q:Value/*:HHQuoteData') as a(d);

select a.d.query('.')
from @x.nodes('server/requests/Session.setDocumentRq/session/data/policy/*:AdditionalData/*:KeyValuePair/*:Value/*:HHQuoteData') as a(d);
```